# Password singleline how to

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

I need to programatically set `EditText` to display text like password and I also need this `EditText` to be single line.

I know how to make `EditText` to display text like password:

```
editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

I also know how to display `EditText` on single line:

```
editText.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
editText.setSingleLine();
```

I don't know how to combine these two. When I put these lines of code together, the `EditText` is not working. Even the software keyboard can't be displayed for it.

Does anyone of you guys know how to solve my problem? Thanks in advance for your answer(s).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally did it. For those who have the same problem the correct approach is to combine the two requests but in the different order than I did it before. So you should do:

```
editText.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
editText.setSingleLine();
editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Confirmed, order matters. GJ Google.

Comment: for same, in password field if I press Shift+Enter, text disappear for few moment and again come....any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

To make `EditText` conceal password characters, add the `password` attribute to the relevant element in your layout.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:password

It can also be done programmatically

```
        import android.text.InputType;
        import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;

        //.....

        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        editText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: How could be this combined with the fact, I need the component to be single line (it can't be higher than one line)? As I wrote in my question `editText.setSingleLine();` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In XML file Type

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: I would like to do it programatically not declaratively.